# PHP Unlink to remove old images via regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, glob, unlink

I'm trying to make a php script that will search a specific path in my website and remove a series of images that are old and unused.

They can be ending in either `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.gif`, `.png` and some also have `.webp` appended onto those that I have just mentioned.

The format of the images usually ends in: `-xxxx-xxxx-.extension` for example:

- 32x32.png.webp
- 50x150.png
- 720x1024.gif
- 1920x1920.jpeg.webp

The following regex detects them all correctly as far as I can see:

- `^(.+[0-9]+.[0-9]+\.(png|gif|jpe?g)\.?(webp)?)$`

I've tried the following, but for some reason it's not doing anything:

```
<?php
    $glob = glob('/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/*');
    foreach($glob as $file) {
        if(preg_match('^(.+[0-9]+.[0-9]+\.(png|gif|jpe?g)\.?(webp)?)$', $file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
?>
```

My directory `/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/` contains multiple folders with images inside, some examples below:

- `/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/y-icon-sprite-213x300.png`
- `/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/01/desx-yopy-small-150x150.png`
- `/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/old/maximumload-web-1920x1920.png`
- `/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/old/maximumload-web-1920x1920.png.webp`
- `/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/ex/new/old-storage-720x500.png`

## Recursive:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";

    function rsearch($folder, $pattern_array) {
        $return = array();
        $iti = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
        foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iti) as $file){
            if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), $pattern_array)){
                $return[] = $file;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
    $filepaths = rsearch('/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/', array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'webp') );

    foreach($filepaths as $file) {
        /* The following line prints the correct paths*/
        $filename = $file->getFilename();
        $filepath = $file->__toString();
        $filenamenew = end((explode('/', $filepath)));
        echo var_dump($filename);
        echo var_dump($filenamenew);
        echo var_dump($filepath);
        if(preg_match('/^(.+[0-9]+.[0-9]+\.(png|gif|jpe?g)\.?(webp)?)$/‌​', $filename)) {
            /*unlink($file);*/
            echo "FOUND:" . $filepath . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

## Output (Short:

```
string(21) "videos_background.png"
string(21) "videos_background.png"
string(70) "/home/HOSTACCO/public_html/f1/docs/uploads/static/videos_background.png"

string(29) "videos_background-150x150.png"
string(29) "videos_background-150x150.png"
string(78) "/home/HOSTACCO/public_html/f1/docs/uploads/static/videos_background-150x150.png"
```

The only issue is that the preg_match isn't working, not sure what I've done wrong: https://regex101.com/r/EMrI0N/1

Comment: `preg_match(` is missing an opening quote, is that your actual code? You also are missing delimiters.

Comment: @chris85 I've updated it to show my code, It's for a 1 time run of code and that missing quote was an accident when copying it over. As I made a small change to the regex.

Comment: You are still missing delimiters on the regex. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php You also may want to take off the leading anchor and `.+` since it looks like you only care about the ending.

Comment: @chris85 I'm not exactly sure how to use them in regards to regex for PHP https://regex101.com/r/EMrI0N/1

Comment: Try `preg_match('/^(.+[0-9]+.[0-9]+\.(png|gif|jpe?g)\.?(webp)?)$/'`

Comment: How would I print a list of files instead of unlinking them, just to double check that it's correct? I tried `echo $file . "\r\n";` but the php file is just blank. I'm not getting any errors from the code which I can't understand why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133020/discussion-between-chris85-and-ryflex).

Comment: Well, `glob()` is not recursive to begin with.

Comment: @chris85 If I echo $file it prints the full path of each file. For example `/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/old/maximumload-web-1920x1920.png`

Comment: @Ryflex There are hidden characters there (or SO added them?). See https://regex101.com/r/CA2gej/1 `var_dump` is better for debugging then `echo`.

Comment: @chris85 Indeed there is hidden characters, it's a SplFileInfo object, I've trimmed it down by using `$value = $file->getPathName();` but it still shows a object rather than a string like the following: `string(66) "/home/HOSTACC/public_html/fx/upd/old/maximumload-web-1920x1920.png"`

Comment: Try some magic, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring `$value = $file->getPathName()->__toString();`

Comment: Hmm, Appears my edit earlier never came through, I said that I had managed to get it to a string but regex part still wasn't working. See my latest edit

Comment: Use the `@` to tag. So `$filename` is now a string? The magic function is only being used on `$filepath` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @chris85 If you look at my update & the output, it still isn't working, it should print the `FOUND` and a file path if it finds it.

Comment: @Ryflex the answer (which doesn't tell you how to programmatically fix the issue) is verbatim what I said hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a non-printing control character embedded in your regular expression. Copying and pasting your code from here to [3v4l.org shows](https://3v4l.org/pXQUE):

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '�' in /in/pXQUE on line 4
```

I've manually rekeyed it and now it [works](https://3v4l.org/dtO3L):

```
FOUND:videos_background-150x150.png
```

I suggest either rekeying in your source, or copying mine from 3v4l.